# Two Ethernet, One NIC, Two networks each with a switch

Tags: network-adapter

I have a linux computer running yocto. The linux PC box has one Ethernet port built in, and I have created another Ethernet port using a USB-to-Ethernet adapter. I only have one NIC in the linux PC now.

One Ethernet cable connects my linux PC to an online network switch. The other Ethernet cable connects my linux PC to a completely offline network switch. I am trying to pull data from another device connected on the offline network and then send the data via the other (online) network connection out to a public facing server.

I have seen ideas for using crossover cables, but I am not sure if that would work in my case. There might be too many offline devices to do crossover cable connections for each. The other idea is to add another NIC to the linux PC.

Is having two NICs the only solution? Or, how can I view a list of devices on the offline network switch and point my main linux PC at any one of the offline devices?

Also, I have seen solutions for two online networks, but my problem is finding solutions for one online, one offline. When both ethernet cables are plugged in, I still do not see any connections or routes to the offline network devices. I would only have access to the regular online network devices.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by online and offline.  The connection to the Internet?  Are these different subnets (by IP address) or just physically separate?

Comment: Your question is non-sensical, and seems to confuse hardware/ethernet configuration with higher abstraction layers of routing.  You probably need to look into NAT and packet forwarding - if both NICS are connected to switches you don't need to use cross-over cables - although most non-ancient switches don't care and will auto-negotiate straight through or cross-over connections.

Comment: On/Off does refer to connection to the Internet. They do have different subnets, and they are physically separate, with the one exception that the linux PC has one ethernet cable to offline + one to online. The offline can absolutely not connect to the outside Internet directly, due to having devices emitting sensitive data.  I need to be able to examine the data on the linux PC, and then securely send it out to Internet to a cloud service. I have the sending (sample) encrypted data to the cloud working now, but I am having trouble collecting the realtime data from another offline device.